# Visual Studio 2013 / Open all files of a specific extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have to make a huge refactoring of an ASP .NET MVC project and I was wondering if there is an option to open all .cshtml files with an option in Visual Studio, instead of opening each file. 
I have more than 200 files :/

The aim of this manipulation is to see compilation error in the .cshtml files.

Comment: What's wrong with using the "errors" window?

Comment: "errors" window is fine, but errors in .cshtml files are not detected during compilation unless they are opened in VS

Comment: Yuo can drag & drop files from explorer which would be a really quick way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you can do this with a Macro.

My best suggestion would be to install this Addon:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b

It should be possible to have a macro to do this.

I suggest that you consider how you're going to do this though, as opening 200+ files is probably going to make Visual Studio unresponsive!

*Alternatively!* (and no, I don't work for them)

Get a copy of Resharper and set it to analyze the entire solution for errors, I believe it will show .cshtml problems too.

Comment: A macro is a great solution, thanks ! The code of my macro is available at http://pastebin.com/10T80aAU, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can type .cshtml in the Solution Explorer search box and it will show you all files with this extension. Then you can easily select and open them at once.

Comment: I like your solution which is very simple, but I would like to have something automated.